# Grant Amazon ML permission to read from Amazon S3 programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I am developing an Amazon Machine Learning application and am reading my data from amazon s3. I ran into a read permission error and found [a solution using amazon explorer.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/dg/reference.html)  I was wondering if there is a way to grant Amazon ML read-write permissions using code , maybe using aws cli or via boto sdk.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer solutions for aws-cli.

After creating S3 bucket policy(`ml_bucket_policy.json`) based on [the developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/dg/reference.html), just run `$ aws cli s3api put-bucket-policy` command to assign the bucket policy.

```
$ aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket YOUR_BUCKET_NAME --policy file://ml_bucket_policy.json
```

Be warned that you need two kinds of bucket policy.

- One is for reading data sources.
- Another is for creating batch predictions

Comment: Still getting the error: Could not access 's3://bucket/trainData.csv'. Either there is no file at that location, or the file is empty, or you have not granted us read permission. I assure u the files are there and non-empty  , and I created the json file as in the example.

Comment: I'm sure your bucket policy's resource path does not match where your S3 files reside.
What happens if you specify S3 path pattern just `*` as follows:

    ...
    "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>",
    "Condition": { "StringLike": { "s3:prefix": [ "*" ] } }
    ...
    "Action": "s3:GetObject",
    "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>/*" ]

Comment: I removed the conditional statement altogether.

Comment: {


"Statement": [

{

"Effect": "Allow",

"Principal": { "Service": "machinelearning.amazonaws.com" },

"Action": "s3:GetObject",

"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"

},

{

"Effect": "Allow",

"Principal": {"Service": "machinelearning.amazonaws.com"},

"Action": "s3:ListBucket",

"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"

}
]
}

Comment: here's the code i am using :  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221281/amazon-s3-unable-to-create-a-datasource)

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an answer.
Create a folder in your bucket. Put the file in the folder. And make sure:

"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/foldername/*"

"s3:prefix": "foldername/*"

NOT your filename